# How to enable user interaction on UITableViewCell contentView while in edit mode?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

Is it possible to enable user interaction on the contentView while in edit mode?

Comment: Did you try `allowsSelectionDuringEditing`?

Comment: Excellent, that'll do the trick ;]

Comment: @KennyTM Can you make your comment an official answer so hveveris can accept it and others can upvote it?

Comment: @gerry3: Done. I added that as a comment because "interaction" can be something other than selection (e.g. swipe gesture, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by interaction you mean "selection", then set the [`allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelectionDuringEditing) to YES.

Comment: UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[tableView allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES];